# Login in via curl then open that page logged in

Tags: php, cookies, curl, header

I'm trying the following code to send post data to the login form, then reload that page in the browser as a logged in user. somehow it's not saving the cookie, and reusing it for the header() function, can the same thing as header be done by calling curl again after sending the login details?

```
..

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , false );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST , false );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $defined_vars['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 1);

// Apply the XML to our curl call
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);

$data = curl_exec($ch);

setcookie($cookie);
header('location: ' . $url);

die();
```

Comment: Is this for the same domain? If not then its impossible. If it is then I just don't get it. Also, no reason for someone to die at the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can login using cURL. And do whatever you have to do using cURL.
I'm not sure if you can restore this cookie and reuse it for further use. 
You can pass a string as a identifier for your cookie in cURL. I'm not sure if you can use it to load the cookie elsewhere... Maybe, maybe not. However, the following code works just fine. At least for the things I need.

Good luck.

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL , "http://www.example.com/login.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "login=" . $login . "&password=" . $password . "&submit=submit");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies");
$response= curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Do not forget you have to use the same cookie key for all other actions you intend to perform in this domain..

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL , "http://www.example.com/datapageyouneed.php");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookies");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookies");
$reponse= curl_exec ($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Answer (score 1):

that's impossible
and looks like phishing.
let user login himself.

Comment: You almost got the Haiku, but it's 5-7-5, not 5-5-7.

Comment: i should be able to do this with javascript now.